# Which plugin is used for writing C# and YAML code in Open Live Writer App?

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, windows-live-writer

I used Open Live Writer windows app for writing the blogs, but I don’t know how to add the C# and YAML code in the blog. So, can anyone suggest me which plugin can I install for writing C# and YAML code in Open Live Writer app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the C# and Yaml code in the blog by adding the Source Code Plugin. You, can add Source Code Plugin to your OpenLiveWriter by following this [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/27/source-code-plug-in-for-wordpress-blogs-using-open-live-writer/)

Comment: Thanks Mani, The above source code plugin doesn't contain `YAML` formatting support. But it's working for remaining programming languages like c#, Java etc...